# Using context and intents with reflection

Tags: android, android-intent, reflection, android-context

I'm using reflection to invoke a method which needs to start activity with intent.
When I invoke the method and I get an "getApplicationContext on a null object reference" exception.
I do not want to pass a context parameter to the method with the invoke.
How can I use intents or get the context?
getbaseContext and getApplicationContext returns null.
I can't pass a context parameter cause I invoke a method which not written by me.

Comment: "I do not want to pass a context parameter to the method with the invoke." - If the method needs a `Context`, you have to give it a `Context`. What's the problem with passing one to your method?

Comment: Please post more code. It is difficult to understand your problem from your description.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, to get the context static:

```
private static Context context;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return MyApplication.context;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I have not mention but I invoke a method of application which not wrote by me.

Comment: ZachBublil you were actually clear, it's the respondents who copy/pasted an inappropriate answer that did not take into account the specificity of your question. This type of inappropriate answering happens quite often on this site.